# Get query string as function parameters on flask

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to get query string as function parameters on flask?
For example, the request will be like this.

```
http://localhost:5000/user?age=15&gender=Male
```

And hope the code similar to this.

```
@app.route("/user")
def getUser(age, gender):
...
```

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are willing to write a decorator, anything is possible:

```
from functools import wraps

def extract_args(*names, **names_and_processors):
    user_args = ([{"key": name} for name in names] +
        [{"key": key, "type": processor}
            for (key, processor) in names_and_processors.items()])

    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            final_args, final_kwargs = args_from_request(user_args, args, kwargs)
            return f(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator if len(names) < 1 or not callable(names[0]) else decorator(names[0])

def args_from_request(to_extract, provided_args, provided_kwargs):
    # Ignoring provided_* here - ideally, you'd merge them
    # in whatever way makes the most sense for your application
    results = {}
    for arg in to_extract:
        result[arg["key"]] = request.args.get(**arg)
    return provided_args, results
```

Usage:

```
@app.route("/somewhere")
@extract_args("gender", age=int)
def somewhere(gender, age):
    return jsonify(gender=gender, age=age)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I looked for. :)

Comment: `is_callable` is not defined

Comment: Wow, amazed that survived this long! Thanks for helping make the answer better!

Comment: This is a good answer, I ended up revamping it to use type annotations and inspection to drop the need for having to list the arguments in the decorator, see my other answer about "flask-publisher".

Answer (score 1):

Flask views themselves do not have obligatory args. You can write:

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/user")
def getUser():
    age = request.args.get('age')
    gender = request.args.get('gender')
```

Comment: This is not an answer. The question specifically asks for being able to pass query parameters as parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting [Flask-Publisher](https://github.com/linsomniac/flask-publisher) and adding "@publish()" decorator before your getUser function:

```
from publisher import publish

@app.route("/user")
@publish()
def getUser(age:int, gender):
...
```

This uses inspection to get the arguments, optionally uses type annotations to convert the incoming arguments, and pulls the values from the GET/POST data.