# URL Builder TypeError error() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have been struggling to understand how this is causing an error because it looks the same as all the others one that are correct.

I want to pass a variable into `url_for` with flask but I keep getting a `TypeError`

```
@app.route('/membership/register/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("NewForm.html", error=False)
    elif request.method == "POST":
      checker = datetime.utcnow()
      if (checker.minute % 2) == 0:
        error = False
        error_type = "username"
      else:
        error = False
        error_type = "terms"
      if error == False:
        message = 'success'
      elif error == True:
        message = 'error'
      else:
        message = 'arbitrageerror'
      print error_type, message
      return redirect(url_for(message , error_msg = error_type ))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('arbitrageerror'))


@app.route('/register/success', methods=["GET"])
def success():
  if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("register_sucess.html", error=True)

@app.route('/register/arbitrageerror', methods=["GET"])
def error404():
  if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("error404.html")

@app.route('/register/error', methods=["GET"], error_msg = error_type)
def error(error_msg):
    if error_msg == "username":
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("register_error.html")
    if error_msg == "terms":
        return "NO Terms"
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError
TypeError: error() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

When I run it I get both variables printed but then I cannot get the `url_for` with the added variable to intake the variable. I am not sure if I am not passing it correctly to the handler. The `redirect(url_for((message, error_msg=error_type))` is the line that I need help with and then the actual function for the `def error(error_msg)`

I have looked at all the documentation and it looks like I am using the correct syntax. Also when I run it I get the following printout

```
Terms error
127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2019 23:37:52] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2019 23:37:52] "GET /register/error?error_msg=Terms HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The first line tells me that I have the variables defined correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: url_for() accepts the name of a function as first argument, and one or more keyword arguments, each corresponding to the variable part of URL

Answer (score 0):

As per flask document, `url_for` accepts the name of the function as its first argument and any number of keyword arguments, each corresponding to a variable part of the URL rule. Unknown variable parts are appended to the URL as query parameters.

Eg.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index'

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return 'login'

@app.route('/user/<username>')
def profile(username):
    return '{}\'s profile'.format(username)

with app.test_request_context():
    print(url_for('index'))
    print(url_for('login'))
    print(url_for('login', next='/'))
    print(url_for('profile', username='John Doe'))
```

URL:

```
/
/login
/login?next=/
/user/John%20Doe
```

More details

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#url-building

Answer (score 0):

```python
@app.route('/register/error', methods=["GET"])
def error():
    error_msg = request.args.get('error_msg')
    if error_msg == "username":
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render_template("register_error.html")
    if error_msg == "terms":
        return "NO Terms"
```

Reason:

The `error_msg` is a query parameter, which will not be passed as a function argument to `error()` function.

You have to get the query parameter from the `request` object.

If you want to have query parameters passed as function arguments, follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34597794/2644759

Comment: This is the best description I have gotten. I am new to this and am still a little confused. So if I understand you correctly, if I want to get it to work then I will have to build a decoder to handle the `error_msg` argument. Now I am a little confused as to what a query parameter is and why it wont be passed as a function argument? I am also not sure what the difference between **query parameters** and **function arguments** are? If you could explain or point me to some documentation that would be much appreciated.